# PTIJ: can the hunchback of notre dame convert

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Torah in Deuteronomy 10:16 states

> וּמַלְתֶּ֕ם אֵ֖ת עׇרְלַ֣ת לְבַבְכֶ֑ם וְעׇ֨רְפְּכֶ֔ם לֹ֥א תַקְשׁ֖וּ עֽוֹד׃
> Cut away, therefore, the thickening about your hearts and stiffen your necks no more.

I’m curious therefore, is there a heter for the hunchback of notre dame to convert to Judaism?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: If people with thick hearts can convert, people with stiff necks can too.

Comment: If he had a decent chiropractor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rabbi Yehuda seems to not have an issue with hunchbacks - see [Mishnah Bechoros 7:1]
[1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bekhorot.7.1?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&lang=bi):

> בַעֲלֵי הַחֲטוֹטֶרֶת, רַבִּי יְהוּדָה מַכְשִׁיר
>
> A hunchback: Rabbi Yehuda considers him fit.

Rambam notes that it is dependent on which way the back bends. See [Mishnah Torah, Hilchos Shofar, Sukkah, V'Lulav 8:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Shofar%2C_Sukkah_and_Lulav.8.3?ven=Mishneh_Torah,_trans._by_Eliyahu_Touger._Jerusalem,_Moznaim_Pub._c1986-c2007&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he):

> הָיָה עָקוּם לְפָנָיו שֶׁהֲרֵי שְׁדֵרוֹ כְּגַב בַּעַל חֲטוֹטֶרֶת פָּסוּל. הָיָה עָקוּם לַאֲחוֹרָיו כָּשֵׁר שֶׁזּוֹ הִיא בְּרִיָּתוֹ
>
> If it is bent forward so that its shidrah appears like a hunchback, it is unacceptable. If it is bent backwards, it is kosher, since that is its natural pattern of growth.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm sorry if it is not funny enough?!!

Comment: What if he only hunches due to lack of confidence? Or maybe he grew tall at an early age and stood out from his peers? Or bad shoes? A simple one-on-one interview with his conversion sponsor could clear this right up.

Comment: @Here's an upvote to counterbalance against the naysayer! Nay